# What is the basic idea behind calculation of area?

Tags: geometry, logic, area, math-history

The system of calculating area in terms of ***square units*** is pretty philosophical and not very intuitive. It must have taken a great amount of time for humanity to arrive at such a convention and to spread it across different societies.
My question is about finding basics of such a convention and should the person who first thought of calculating areas in square units be regarded a great philosopher equivalent to Newton and Einstein?
Moreover, could we have evolved a different method of calculating areas?

Comment: This seems like a question for the [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes. I added that in tags.

Comment: The tag is helpful, but it predates the creation of the dedicated [HSM.SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) community. Posing the question directly to that community may get better results. (That site has much lower traffic than Math.SE, too, so the chances are good of getting more attention.)

Comment: Thanks for advice

Comment: "pretty philosophical" ??? It seems quite natural: for lenght, we start from a "unit lenght" and count how many times the unit lenght is contained into the measured lenght. For area, we start from a "unit area" and...

Comment: Still the notion of unit area is not that intuitive, especially in prehistoric times.

Comment: Could we have evolved a different method of calculating areas?

Comment: IMHO, a rectangular (or a square) shape is less natural than a circular shapes (moon, sun, circular wave when you drop a stone in water) ; the idea of measuring areas by reference to squares (or rectangles) should have come to the mind of people familiar with using (clay) bricks and/or building rectangular shape housing.

Comment: It's difficult to know how to address this question. If your question is historical, you should post it on the other site, as already mentioned. If you're asking for a justification why a square is the most practical unit for subdivision in area computations, then you can approach it by considering alternatives - a circle is highly regular but doesn't tessellate. The only regular polygons that do have 3,4 and 6 sides. The hexagon has no advantage over the equilateral triangle as the former is a tessellation of the latter. So that leaves us with 3 or 4. In fact, 3 is used (isometric grid)...

Comment: 10 if u take units. 20 if u count half of units.

Comment: ...(continued) so perhaps the choice of 4 (square) has something to do with the preference of right angled axes. You can find other justifications such as 3-D analogues of each for volume subdivision (a cube/cuboid tessellates, but not a tetrahedron) so that's a further advantage to choosing a square in 2-D, but honestly, I have no idea if that sort of thinking factored into the history of why a square unit was chosen. Again, you should post this on the best site for the question. This is not it.

Comment: Yes, I have already posted this question on the other site as suggested by Blue. Thanks Deepak for letting me know about isometric grid.

Comment: Measuring the area of a region by asking how many little $1 \text{cm} \times 1 \text{cm}$ squares you can fit inside it seems like a totally natural idea. I think many people would have had that idea, even non-mathematicians. Let's say you're living in ancient civilization and selling a plot of land or something, you need a way to describe how large the plot of land is. A square centimeter of cloth (for example) is something you can hold in your hand so it's very intuitive.

Comment: @Deepak The historical aspect might be a red herring here. Area was known to the Greeks and probably to the Egyptians and Babylonians - basically, the origin of area is probably prehistorical, and the oldest historical sources probably use it just as fluently and casually as modern sources, so they wouldn't answer the OP's real question. I suspect area is just much more natural and obvious an idea than OP gives it credit for, so a real answer would be a mathematical explanation of the intuition behind area.

Comment: But still the shape of plot weren't always regular(square, rectangle, etc)  and hence setting on a perticular shape eg. Square shouldn't be that obvious as described. And how would you justify the use of square units for measuring areas of curves and circles?

Comment: @VikasMourya I'd guess for most of history people were happy to ignore those issues, just by using a small unit square and then calling that "good enough". Maybe they intuitively had a limit kind of idea in their minds. Taking those questions seriously, though, leads one to the goal of rigorously defining area -- which is something much more difficult, that was only done by mathematicians in like the late 1800s (I would guess). For example there is something called "[Jordan content](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Jordan_measure)" or "Jordan measure" that was defined around that time.

Answer (score 1):

Area is a property of a planar region. The formulation in terms of "unit area" comes from the fact that *many of the properties of planar regions that human beings care about are translation-invariant*. For example, how much grain or how many sheep a region of land can support, or how long it will take one person to till it.

All of these quantities have two important properties:

1. Translation invariance. If $A$ and $B$ are the same shape and size but in different places, then $f(A)=f(B)$.
2. Additivity. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint regions, then $f(A\cup B)=f(A)+f(B)$.

These two properties were presumably intuitively obvious to ancient humans, without them having to formulate them precisely or even consciously. From these properties it follows that if you take any given shape $U$, then for any region $A$, $f(A)$ is determined by $f(U)$ and by how many disjoint copies of $U$ it takes to tile $A$. Therefore, how many copies of $U$ it takes to tile a region is a good measure of the "size" of land. It's surely visually very obvious that any region can be reasonably tiled with small squares.

Of course, all this is just a very complicated, modern way of saying something very simple: since any given 1x1 meter square can contain the same amount of wheat, well, obviously if I know how many square meters cover a given region of land, I know how much wheat I can put on it.

Comment: But still the shape of plot weren't always regular(square, rectangle, etc)  and hence setting on a perticular shape eg. Square shouldn't be that obvious as described. And how would you justify the use of square units for measuring areas of curves and circles?

Comment: @VikasMourya Listen, if you're going to be using a rectangle, and you're not overthinking things, I think most people would naturally settle on a square just because... it's a square. For curved areas, you can tile a curved area with squares just fine, you just have to not worry too much about the approximation incurred by not being able to tile all the way to the edge, which a non-mathematician wouldn't.

Comment: But still I think that idea of using square units for measuring areas of curves shouldn't have been that straightforward.

Comment: It is possible that the idea of measuring by rectangular units has come with weaving: the amount of surface that a weaver can do in a day multiplied by the number of days, etc.

Comment: @VikasMourya That's because you're thinking like a mathematician, not like a normal person in 3000 BC. Also remember that it's a very natural step to just use smaller squares so that you can get closer to the edge and fill out the curved region better, and it's intuitively obvious that you can always keep using smaller squares to get a better fit.